# Sudo error ubuntu server

Tags: networking, server

Hello I am using ubuntu server and I am getting an error when I try to use sudo:

`sudo: unable to resolve host ira: Resource temporarily unavailable`

I have looked this error up and people say its something with `/etc/hosts/`

Here is mine:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain   localhost
::1             localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

What is wrong with this file?
Also what could cause this? was it someone changing this file by hand or is it the system that did it?

Thanks, Ira.

Comment: Ok thanks for your explanations, good to know ! :)

Comment: If you have any further questions about reviewing, there is an Ask Ubuntu chatroom especially for that purpose: [Raiders of the Lost Downboat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3877/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add in your `/etc/hosts` something like

```
 127.0.1.1    your-machine
```